# object Neo4j is not a member of package org.neo4j.spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to build Spark application using neo4j connector but I am getting an error:

```
object Neo4j is not a member of package org.neo4j.spark
import org.neo4j.spark.Neo4j
```

when I try to import Neo4j. My build.sbt file looks like this:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.neo4j" % "neo4j-connector-apache-spark_2.12" % "4.1.4_for_spark_2.4"

//libraryDependencies += "org.neo4j" % "neo4j-connector-apache-spark_2.11" % "4.0.1_for_spark_2.4"

//libraryDependencies += "neo4j-contrib" %% "neo4j-spark-connector" % "2.1.0-M4"
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.0"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.0"
```

And my code in scala:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.neo4j.spark.Neo4j

object first {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    def main(args: Array[String]) {

      val conf = new SparkConf()
        .setAppName("Test-neo4j-skel") // App Name
        .setMaster("local[*]") // local mode

      val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

      val neo = Neo4j(sc)

      val rdd = neo.cypher("MATCH (n:Person) RETURN id(n) as id ").loadRowRdd
      rdd.count
```

Thank You.

Comment: I think I responded to a similar question of yours yesterday. Assuming you have the correct sbt dependencies, the first occurrence of `%` should be `%%` all the time, to let sbt resolve the Scala version for you. `libraryDependencies += "org.neo4j" %% "neo4j-connector-apache-spark" % "<version>_for_spark_2.4"` Check your version for spark.

Comment: @AlinGabrielArhip In case of this dependency ```%%``` does not work and sbt is throwing an error. My Spark version is 2.4.0.

Answer (score 1):

`import org.neo4j.spark.Neo4j` you're leveraging the old APIs.

Please read the documentation:

https://neo4j.com/docs/spark/current/quickstart/

this in particular contains info about how to read data with a Cypher query:

https://neo4j.com/docs/spark/current/reading/#read-query